# Hyper-V is disabled after restart of windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio, xamarin.android, windows-10, hyper-v

I am trying to work with Visual Studio Mobile App (Xamarin.Forms), so as it is said I have to enable Hyper-V on my Win 10 and then setup Visual Studio.
So I follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin&pivots=windows#hyper-v) guide in order to enable it, but after enabling [Hyper-V from Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/bg-bg/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration-images/win/03-hyper-v-settings-w158.png#lightbox) and restarting the PC it returns disabled/unchecked.
I tried to execute **bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto** in order to make it launch automatically after restart, but still not the solution. Visual Studio says that Hyper-V is disabled and can't visualize the app. Any ideas will be great. Thanks in advance.

P.S My PC is using Intel processor and in Task Manager -> Performance -> Visualization is **Enabled**, so not the BIOS setting is the problem.

P.S2 I tried the HAXM, but when installing it says that my PC is not compatible.

Comment: Which CPU and did you enable memory protection in the windows security settings? Also is VT-d enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: Hello. I am using intel i5-5200U, I tried:
1. To enable memory protection
2. My VT-d is enabled in bios
3. Deleting VMware (if this was even a problem)

Comment: Have you tried to  enable `Hyper-V` [through Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v#enable-the-hyper-v-role-through-settings)?

Comment: And what version of Windows is your computer?

Comment: Hello. When I enable Hyper-V the computer asks for restart. After restart is disabled again. My win version is PRO.

Comment: Exact version of windows is 1909 and OS build 18363.592

Comment: @Greeed disable memory protection and enable VT-d. Memory protection requires using second level address translation to also support Hyper-v which is not present on that CPU IIRC.

Comment: Hello @Mgetz . This one I tried already and sadly not the solution. I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Check if "**Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management**" is on "**Automatic**" in the services.msc.

- Windows key + R
- Type services.msc and press OK
- Search for "Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management"
- Right click and click properties
- Select automatic by startup type
- Press apply and close

I had the same issue and this was the fix for me.

[image: image for example]

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response! In my services.msc I don't have Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management service. Just to say again I followed the Enable Hyper-V using PowerShell guide....